# Problema con funciones dentro de selects - SQL Server

Tags: sql, subconsultas

hola es bastante complicado de que entiendan la estructura pero voy a tratar de explicarme lo mas posible:
Tengo 4 tablas relacionadas entre si, la tabla catalogo de productos que es la tabla raiz, de ella descienden la tabla producto que tiene variantes de cada producto del catalogo, a su vez hay una tabla EmbarqueProducto que a su vez tiene una tabla descendiente embarque. (no he hecho yo esta estructura, asi la recibi). Estoy haciendo la siguiente busqueda:

```
select Producto.Modelo,Producto.Descripcion,
(--fecha cierre
select distinct nombre as Embarque,Embarque.Descripcion,fechaCierre,FechaEstimadaArribo
from producto as pe
inner join embarqueProducto on EmbarqueProducto.ProductoId = pe.ProductoID
inner join Embarque on Embarque.EmbarqueID = EmbarqueProducto.EmbarqueId
where pe.ProductoCatalogo_ProductoCatalogoID = Producto.ProductoCatalogoID for json path
) Embarque
from ProductoCatalogo as Producto
where Producto.Modelo = 'HB02-100' for json path
```

que seria: para el producto de catalogo HB02-100 hay un embarque que tiene varias fechas de cierre y de arribo, esta busqueda no arroja error alguno y me da el nombre, descripcion del producto y un array de embarque con todas las fechas disponibles asi

```
[
  {
    "Modelo": "HB02-100",
    "Descripcion": "Luminaria High Bay (UFO) Alta Eficiencia",
    "Embarque": [
      {
        "Embarque": "Embarque Test",
        "fechaCierre": "2021-07-24T00:00:00",
        "FechaEstimadaArribo": "2021-10-22T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Embarque": "Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) ENE-2020",
        "Descripcion": "Equipos HIGH BAY de última generación de Alta Eficiencia y con sistema de Antideslumbramiento",
        "fechaCierre": "2221-11-11T00:00:00",
        "FechaEstimadaArribo": "2021-02-03T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Embarque": "Luminaria HIGH BAY (UFO) MAY-2020",
        "Descripcion": "Equipos HIGH BAY de última generación de Alta Eficiencia y con sistema de Antideslumbramiento",
        "fechaCierre": "2021-03-15T00:00:00",
        "FechaEstimadaArribo": "2021-06-13T00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

bien, yo lo que necesito es el embarque que pertence a la fecha mas cercana de cierre por lo que hago:

```
select distinct nombre as Embarque,Embarque.Descripcion,min(fechaCierre) Cierre,FechaEstimadaArribo
```

y obtengo este error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
Column 'Embarque.Nombre' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

con lo cual trato de agrupar con group by Nombre y el error salta a Embarque.Descripcion

No se que hacer...

Comment: ¿necesitas que te devuelva un solo embarque, el que tiene la menor fecha de cierre?

Comment: si, exactamente!

Comment: si solo incluyo la funcion min(fechaCierre) me selecciona la fecha menor, pero al poner los otros campos da error, habra que usar group by con los otros campos pero no me doy cuenta como (soy muy novato con sql,3 dias de aprendizaje)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes valerte de la cláusula `top` para seleccionar una cantidad determinada de registros, en este caso 1 registro, y combinarla con `order by` para ordenar primero por fecha, de manera que el registro que devuelva sea el registro que tiene la primera fecha así, la sub consulta, tendría una estructura como esta:

```
select top 1 campo1, campo2, campo3
  from tabla 
       [joins]
 where [condiciones]
 order by fechaCierre
```

Trasladando esto a tu consulta, lo que buscas está en la línea de:

```
select   Producto.Modelo
       , Producto.Descripcion
       , (select top 1 
                   nombre as Embarque
                 , Embarque.Descripcion
                 , fechaCierre
                 , FechaEstimadaArribo
            from producto as pe
                 inner join embarqueProducto on EmbarqueProducto.ProductoId = pe.ProductoID
                 inner join Embarque on Embarque.EmbarqueID = EmbarqueProducto.EmbarqueId
           where pe.ProductoCatalogo_ProductoCatalogoID = Producto.ProductoCatalogoID 
           order by fechaCierre
             for json path
         ) Embarque
  from ProductoCatalogo as Producto
 where Producto.Modelo = 'HB02-100' 
   for json path
```

Comment: si funciona, muchas gracias @jachguate, aunque me hubiera gustado saber la causa por la cual no funcionaba de la otra manera

Comment: Funciones como `min()` son agregadores que funcionan en conjunto con una [cláusula `group by`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) o una [cláusula `over`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql), usarlas fuera de ese contexto no tiene sentido y, más importante, no era necesario para el problema que tenías a mano, como ya has podido ver. Un saludo.

Comment: ahora tengo otro problema, al formatear la fechaCierre como habria de esperarse ya no me la toma la clausula order by

Comment: Bueno, es un avance. Si luego investigar e intentar resolverlo por ti mismo sigues encontrando problemas, escribe una nueva pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: si perdon, ya estaba pidiendo sin tratar de resolverlo, al llamar al resultado de la funcion igual al nombre de campo no me lo tomaba, con solo cambiarlo funciono, gracias!! Seguro aparecera la edicion de tu respuesta y mi pedido previo, puedes borrarlo